# Should glute-bridges make my calves ache?

Tags: exercise, muscle, core, hip

I have been given some glute [bridges](http://www.womenshealthmag.com/files/images/1006-poolside-glute-bridge.jpg) to do, to improve the strength of my core and hips, to prevent injury while running. I'm quite weak in this area and after a day and a half,I'm finding it's my calves that are aching, not my hips or core.

Does this mean I'm doing them wrong, or just that because I'm weak at that area, I'm over compensating and supporting myself with the calves?

[Like this](http://www.womenshealthmag.com/files/images/1006-poolside-glute-bridge.jpg) but without the knee-squeeze and with raising one lower leg up in the air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a combination of both. In order to be 100% sure I would need to see how you do it. In any case, if it's unsupportable pain I'm guessing there's something wrong.

If you are ALWAYS sore after doing that exercise (even after a few weeks of doing them), you might be compensating.

Concentrate on the glute contraction and everything should fall into place.

Comment: To add to this: Check your form, and make sure that when you do the bridge, that you aren't raising up on your toes. I see people do this quite often in various exercises when they are trying to get a little "more" out of the exercise. You may not even realize you are doing it.

Comment: As suggested, I've been concentrating on the form and the aching is going away. I can't say for sure that it was related to the bridge but they are getting easier.